# Is it possible to define the name of the temp dir using mkdtemp?

Tags: python

I'm using Python's [mkdtemp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) method as defined in the *tempfile* module which creates a temp dir at the specified location (using dir argument) or uses default tempdir location if *dir* argument is not supplied.

My question is if is it possible to control the name of tmp dir that is created? For example, I want to be able to create the tempdir with the username information.

Comment: Per the documentation, you need to make use of `dir` when calling the method: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp

Comment: Can you put the username in the `prefix` or `suffix`? The whole point of using something like `mkdtemp` is to let it pick the name for you, guaranteeing uniqueness.

Comment: After supplying the dir argument, mkdtemp creates another tmp directory inside it. My question is if the name of that tmp directory can be controlled by the user.

Comment: @Chris I could do that. If I supply the username in the prefix, it would still go on and append the auto generated alphanumeric characters after it. Same applies for the suffix but in the other direction.

Comment: @KanwarG, yes, that's what it would do. Again, that's the whole _point_ of `mkdtemp` and its cousins. If you want to specify the exact directory name, simply create the directory yourself (and give up the safety guarantees of `mkdtemp`).

Comment: @Chris Okay I see your point. Perhaps I should use it as intended then. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the function signature:

```
tempfile.mkdtemp([suffix=''[, prefix='tmp'[, dir=None]]])
```

You can specify a suffix, prefix, and could even choose the parent directory.

So you could use `suffix = '_john.smith'`, and that would add user information in the directory name.

If you wanted to specify entirely the name (not just prefix or suffix), just use `tempfile.gettempdir()` and append your name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I decided to play around with the dir name and added the username info in the prefix.